# Autohotkey. How will I hit ctrl button just once and not everytime?

Tags: autohotkey

```
shift::SoundSet +1
ctrl::SoundSet -1
```

.......is the script, problem is I need to press ctrl five times if I want my volume to increase five more.

Unlike this:

```
PgUp::SoundSet +3
pgdn::SoundSet -3
```

I just press and hold any of the keys and the volume will just continue to go up
/down and stop if I unpressed so.

Comment: Windows has *StickyKeys* in *Accessibility Options*. Turn it on, and you'll get the effect you want.

Comment: how?............. already turn it on, still the same.

Comment: The "qualifyer" (alt win ctrl shift menu) keys are not set to be repeating items, including numlock scrolllock and capslock. That is part of how the operating system handles it, not the keyboard which only sends out a Key-Up and Key-Dn.  so the issue here is they are not sending a repetition to the AHK itself, wheras every other key would be repeating.  It would be easiest to use repeating keys I had used stuff like Ctrl Kb num keys (the ones on the num pad). Or make a AHK script that detects Ctrl-Dn , and continues to soundset as long as that is true.